# How to get a multi-word synonym as a single entity in solr?

Tags: solr

I have a set of terms that I want to map to a specific phrase at query time. For that I am using `solr.SynonymFilterFactory`. Here is a snippet from `schema.xml`

```
<fieldType name="text_lc" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Here is the `synonyms.txt`

```
cat, bat, mouse => small animals
```

Here is the output of analysis:

[image]

The problem is that small animals are appearing as separate tokens whereas I want to search on **"small animals" as a whole.**

How to get a multi-word synonym as a single entity in solr?

Answer (score 2):

The [new SynonymGraphFilter has specific functionality to handle multi word synonyms](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#FilterDescriptions-SynonymGraphFilter), as these weren't handled properly by the old synonym filter.

Multi word synonyms are still hard to get right, but the new filter at least has a strategy for multi word synonyms.

Example from the reference guide:

```
<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="mysynonyms.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/> <!-- required on index analyzers after graph filters -->
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="mysynonyms.txt"/>
</analyzer>
```

Pay attention to the `FlattenGraphFilterFactory` requirement.